# onMouseLeave not working when leaving an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

For some reason, the `onMouseLeave` event isn't functioning as expected in React. It is firing when I hover over another element such as the navbar or console but doesn't fire when the mouse leaves the element.

```js
function GameCard({name, about, image}) { 

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false)

    return ( 
        <div className={Styles.gameCard} onMouseOver={() => setActive(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setActive(false)}>
            {
                active 
                    ? <div className={Styles.gameCardInfo} >
                        <h1 className={Styles.gameCardName}>{name}</h1>
                        <h2 className={Styles.gameCardAbout}>{about}</h2>
                        <div className={Styles.play}>
                            <Fab color='secondary' onClick={() => console.log('working')}>
                                <PlayArrowIcon/>
                            </Fab>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    : console.log('notactive')
                }
                <img  className={active ? `${Styles.gameCardImage} ${Styles.activeCardImage}` : `${Styles.gameCardImage}`} src={image}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: It [seems to work in the simple case](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/5Leu81ra/), so we really need that MRE to know what's going on in your case.

Comment: Im heading out shortly but if this is any help, this is how the cards are generated, not sure if this is causing any bugs, as the onMouseLeave is firing when i move it to another element, just not when it leaves the actual card.

`
function CardView() { 
    const games = gamesList

    return (
        games.map((game) => {
            return (
                <GameCard name={game.name} about={game.about} image={game.image}/>
            )
        })
    )
} 
`

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix this by applying pointer-events: none to all of the child elements.